# AJAX Toolkit AutoCompleteExtender does not autopostback when clicking suggestion

Tags: asp.net, autopostback, autocompleteextender

Pretty self explanatory.  I have a textbox in an updatepanel that will autopostback when a complete entry is typed, but will not postback when selecting an option from the AutoCompleteExtender.  Any ideas on why this doesn't work or possible workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a workaround.  You'll have to set the autocompleteextender's OnClientItemSelected to a javascript function, then call __doPostBack from said function.

```
function OnJobSelected(source, eventArgs)
        {

            var SourceID = source.get_element().id
            __doPostBack(SourceID, "");
        }
```